# Как создаются альтернативные приложения Вконтакте?

Tags: android, вконтакте

Решил для увеличения опыта в разработке приложений под Android написать своё приложение Вконтакте, несколько раз видел такие приложения от независимых разработчиков.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вообще происходит этот процесс?

Должен ли я договариваться об этом с администрацией Вконтакте?

Придётся ли мне использовать какие нибудь языки, кроме java?

Какими навыками мне нужно для этого овладеть?

Пробовал гуглить, но в интернете информации по этому поводу мало

Answer (score 7, accepted):

На сайте вконтакте под менюшкой есть кнопка "Разработчикам". Жмешь на нее - появляется все, что касается разработки приложений с использованием VK API.

Опять же, гуглится по тому же запросу  vk api.

Очевидно, все, что предоставляется через официальное api - можно делать ни у кого дополнительного разрешения не спрашивая, для обучения там более чем достаточно интересных вещей.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: премного благодарен)